# Book with two main characters/stories. The main guy has a diary he finds that talks to him

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book a while ago and I wanted to read the second one when it came out, but I can't remember the name.

It starts off with the main character, who is on a school research project, and he finds a diary which starts talking to him. The system of magic in the world is that people can absorb magic around them and use it, but it's slowly getting used up. He ends up on the run because his professor finds out about the diary, and the fact the magic is not what he has been taught. He goes on the run from the university and in the end of the book goes to some place and uses enough magic to open a portal to another world.

The other character is a girl on a different world who falls in love with some artist and runs away from her family for him. She finds out she has some magic, but in their society it's considered evil or something, and she goes on the run too.

I really enjoyed the book and can't remember the name. Can anyone help? I lent it to someone so can't find it on my bookshelf either.

Comment: The title made me think this would be harry potter, dissapointing

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90871/magic-leaves-smudges-and-a-sorceress-becomes-a-book

Comment: This has some elements from Roger Zelazny's _Roadmarks_ (the talking diary, which is actually a supercomputer in the form of a book), but other things don't match.

Answer (score 18):

I'm reading this at the moment.  It's **Thief's Magic**, by Trudi Canavan.  From [her website](http://www.trudicanavan.com/books/),

> In one world, Tyen, an archaeology and sorcery student, discovers a sentient book during an expedition to unearth ancient tombs. In another, Rielle, the daughter of rich dye merchants, knows she had forbidden magical ability because she can see Stain, the void left when magic is stripped from the world.

The first book in the **Millenium's Rule** trilogy, the second is **Angel of Storms**.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. :) +1